# Getting an error while building the Game for an Android Phone

Tags: unity, google-play-services

I placed an Admob Plugin in my game. Then I import gamedonia SDK for Facebook connection and Push notification. In editor it's working fine. While compiling it for an Android Phone it generates an error. How can I fix this?

I am using Unity 5.2.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Unity\unity 5.2.1\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoJellyBeanMr2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBeanMr2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$1;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
ignored resource E:\Unity3d 5.2.1 work Space\NGUI\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs\.\PLUGIN_JAR_GOES_HERE
processing archive E:\Unity3d 5.2.1 work Space\NGUI\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs\.\unity-plugin-library.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/unity/
processing com/google/unity/BuildConfig.class...
ignored resource com/google/unity/ads/
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/PluginUtils.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityBannerAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityInterstitialAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityRewardBasedVideoAdListener.class...
processing archive E:\Unity3d 5.2.1 work Space\NGUI\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\bin\classes.jar...
ignored resource .readme
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource android/
ignored resource android/support/
ignored resource android/support/v7/
ignored resource android/support/v7/app/
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$LayoutParams.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$NavigationMode.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$OnMenuVisibilityListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$OnNavigationListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Tab.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$TabListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerArrowDrawableToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DummyDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$HoneycombDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$JellybeanMr2Delegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$5.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$OnPrepareListViewListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$ButtonHandler.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$CheckedItemAdapter.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog$Builder.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$ActionBarDrawableToggleImpl.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV23.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV23$AppCompatWindowCallbackV23.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$5.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$5$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$6.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ListMenuDecorView.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState$SavedState.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState$SavedState$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialogFragment.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatViewInflater.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NavItemSelectedListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$Builder.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$IceCreamSandwichExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$JellybeanExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$LollipopExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$MediaStyle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompatImpl21.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompatImplBase.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$ActionMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$MenuBuilderCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$PanelMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/TwilightCalculator.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/TwilightManager.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/TwilightManager$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/TwilightManager$TwilightState.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$TabImpl.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/appcompat/
processing android/support/v7/appcompat/BuildConfig.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/graphics/
ignored resource android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/
processing android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawableUtils.class...
processing android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable.class...
processing android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable$ArrowDirection.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/text/
processing android/support/v7/text/AllCapsTransformationMethod.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/transition/
processing android/support/v7/transition/ActionBarTransition.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/view/
processing android/support/v7/view/ActionBarPolicy.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ActionMode.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ActionMode$Callback.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/CollapsibleActionView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ContextThemeWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/StandaloneActionMode.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportActionModeWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportMenuInflater.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatSet.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatSet$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/WindowCallbackWrapper.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/view/menu/
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItem.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView$ActionMenuItemForwardingListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView$PopupCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/BaseMenuPresenter.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/BaseMenuWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/BaseWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ExpandedMenuView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ListMenuItemView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ListMenuPresenter.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ListMenuPresenter$MenuAdapter.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuBuilder.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuBuilder$Callback.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuBuilder$ItemInvoker.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuDialogHelper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemImpl.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemImpl$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$ActionProviderWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$CollapsibleActionViewWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$OnActionExpandListenerWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$OnMenuItemClickListenerWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperJB.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperJB$ActionProviderWrapperJB.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuPopupHelper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuPresenter.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuPresenter$Callback.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuView$ItemView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuWrapperFactory.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuWrapperICS.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/SubMenuBuilder.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/SubMenuWrapperICS.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/widget/
processing android/support/v7/widget/AbsActionBarView.class...<message truncated>
```

Comment: Facing the same issue at the moment

Comment: Same here. This is pathetic. https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1118

Comment: @vexe do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @ManojBalajiM The way I did was create an empty project, import each package one by one and see where the build exactly errors out. In my case I got the errors after I added FacebookSDK. So I created an empty project, imported FacebookSDK, and then imported the rest of the plugins we used one by one. Till I finally figured out the jar that was causing the problem (support.jar) - It's tedious but you have to through the process. You could also use 'findstr /spin WHAT WHERE' to search for the duplicates that are mentioned in the error.

Comment: Thanks @vexe its working now. In my case i used gamedonia sdk and admob plugin. this both contain same class name. so i removed two jar files from my assets 1)Android-support-v4.jar and 2) google-play-service.jar. then i compiled. its build successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gamedonia sdk and admob both plugin contain same class name. so i removed two jar files from my assets 1)Android-support-v4.jar and 2) google-play-service.jar. then i compiled. its build successfully.

Whenever import third party sdk's this can be happens. analysis the complete package and remove the unwanted files.